# Cassandra: Is it okay to use a boolean valued column as a clustering column (as part of the primary key)?

Tags: cassandra, boolean, clustering-key

With the Cassandra database system, is it okay to use a boolean valued column as a clustering column (as part of the primary key)? The column will of course not be a partition key, but just one of a bunch of clustering columns.

Is it a negative regarding performance or other considerations?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's is ok to use boolean as one of the clustering columns, especially if you have several

Answer (score 2):

Echoing what Alex said, I think it's ok.

The only negatives I can see, is if:

1. The number of possible values under that particular value is large.
2. The boolean column is your *only* clustering column.

For example, keeping a roster of people in your co-ed softball team (or even a league, for that matter) wouldn't generate enough rows to be a problem.  But if a large social network site implemented it for their user database, that likely would not perform well.  Again though, this is only if it's the *only* clustering key.

But in your case, with it being one of multiple clustering keys, I think you'll be fine.